# Dynamically change html page in frameset in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have prepared HTML file containing frameset. Following is the code

```
<html>
    <frameset rows="55,*">
        <frame name="headinfo" src="headinfo.html" scrolling=no>

        <frameset cols="10,50" frameborder=no border=no framespacing=no>
            <frame name="navinfo" src="navinfo.html" >
            <frame name="bodyinfo" src="bodyinfo.html">
        </frameset>
    </frameset> 
</html>
```

Now content of navinfo.html is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body><div id="vmenu">
    <li><a href="bodyinfo.html#Summary1"target="bodyinfo">Summary 1</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Folder1\Page1.html">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="Folder1\Page2.html">Page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="Folder1\Page3.html">Page3</a></li>
        <li><a href="Folder1\Page4.html">Page4</a></li>
        <li><a href="Folder1\Page5.html">Page5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="bodyinfo.html#Summary2"target="bodyinfo">Summary 2</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Folder2\Page6.html">Page6</a></li>
        <li><a href="Folder2\Page7.html">Page7</a></li>
        <li><a href="Folder2\Page8.html">Page8</a></li>
        <li><a href="Folder2\Page9.html">Page9</a></li>
        <li><a href="Folder2\Page10.html">Page10</a></li>
    </ul>   
</body>
</html>
```

Now when clicked on Page1 on navigation tab, it is opening a new window of page1.html. My problem is i want it to be displayed on same section of html page where bodyinfo.html is displayed. Basically when user clicks on any list item on navigation bar then right section which contains the body part should display that clicked html data.
Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default target for all your links, by using the BASE tag.

```
<head>
<BASE target="bodyinfo">
</head>
```

Alternatively, you can use the target attribute in every link, just like you did with the summary links.

```
<li><a href="Folder1\Page1.html" target="bodyinfo">Page1</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephan for the quick response. It is working as expected